# Simple Past or Past Participle

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Between 1990 and 2000, the number of people living in the UK had increased from 10 million to 50 million, whereas that in Africa had decreased by 50%.

or

Between 1990 and 2000, the number of people living in the UK increased from 10 million to 50 million, whereas that in Africa decreased by 50%.

(A graph that shows information regarding the world population between 1990 and 2000)

Comment: They're both correct as they stand. The choice would be informed by what the previous text was (specifically, is there a reference to an intervening year: 'Let us look at the situation in 2005.' Here, I'd choose 'had increased'.)

Comment: Which one is more appropriate?

Comment: If it's a caption on a graph, you want to use the second.

Comment: What a strange example! In fact the UK population increased from [57M to 59M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demography_of_the_United_Kingdom) in that decade, whereas in Africa it increased from [629M to 808M](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_continents_by_population)

Comment: Could you please explain why it would be more suitable? (or the first one would be incorrect when the caption is provided)

Comment: There is no previous text specifying an interim date (eg 2005) to warrant a second-order past construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this sentence will help you understand better: Between 1990 and 2000, the number of people living in the UK increased from 10 million to 50 million, whereas between 1980 and 1990, the number of people had only increased by (x number of people). 
The past perfect should be used when writing about something in the past, which occurred before another event in the past. Another example: I had learned German before I moved to Germany.

http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html

Comment: I'm enlightened